# Eclipse Luna with JBoss Tools does not export libraries

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-tools

I'm attempting to upgrade our environment to Eclipse Luna w/ JBoss Tools from our current Indigo instance. Most things are sorted well enough, but I'm running into a wall when deploying our application to a JBoss server within Eclipse.

As far as I can see, the lib/ directory of the .ear file generated contains none of the transitive dependencies from maven that we would normally expect to see, and as a result the application does not deploy or run correctly on the server. For clarity, we use the 'use workspace metadata' deployment option on the JBoss server within Eclipse.

By contrast, if I right click on the relevant project within Eclipse and say Export... .ear file, the resulting .ear contains all the .jars that I'd expect inside the lib/ folder (there's over 50 of these things, so it's pretty easy to spot the difference). Subsequently dropping the .ear into the deploy directory of JBoss and starting a server manually has the application working fine.

Has anyone ever encountered this sort of issue within JBoss Tools / Luna, and if so what steps were taken to try and remediate it?

Cheers for any help.
Dave.

EDIT: For what it's worth, this is a JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 5.x server instance, and we're using JBoss EAP 5.2

Comment: Are you the same David from https://developer.jboss.org/message/912690#912690 ? If not, any chance of you giving us access to test the project to reproduce the issue would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Same one I'm afraid - had some help over there but couldn't get to the bottom of the issue and don't have the time at the moment to continue digging deeper. :(

Comment: We have not been able to reproduce this issue and so far everyone only been able to do so on projects they can't share - thus really tricky for us to figure out what is causing the issue ;/ If you have any way of reproducing it with something we can get to see that would be very helpful.